# How pass grouped parameters in command line

Tags: bash, parameters, grouping

I would like to pass three groups of parameters such as:

```
sh run.sh [1,4,6,8] [3,6,10,14] [8,16,32]
```

If possible then how can I access to parameters in script?

Comment: Pass them as 3 strings: `"1,4,6,8" "3,6,10,14" "8,16,32"`

Comment: How do I access them if I pass them as strings?

Comment: Use: `IFS=, read -ra arg1 <<<  "$1"`

Comment: @anubhava You could post that as an answer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass your comma separated numbers as arguments to your script:

```
bash run.sh "1,4,6,8" "3,6,10,14" "8,16,32"
```

Please note I am using `bash` instead of `sh` to be able to use `bash` shell instead of posix `sh`.

Then inside the `run.sh` script, you can use `IFS=, read -ra` to split each argument into shell array:

```
IFS=, read -ra argarr1 <<< "$1"
IFS=, read -ra argarr2 <<< "$2"
IFS=, read -ra argarr3 <<< "$3"
```

And use each array as:

```
for i in "${argarr1[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```